# android-How to make button background non transparent

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

this is an image of my layout :

[image]
as you can see, the button background is semi transparent and gets layout background color .I don't want my button to be transparent
I want to make my button like this :

[image]

I set alpha to 0 didn't work .

Could you help me ? I'm using app compact theme .

thank you

Comment: why don't you simply change the button's background color?

Comment: change the background color of the button

Comment: @waqaslam , I tried this , what happens is this , all the space and padding between buttons gone and they all stick together , I don't know why

Answer (score 2):

Buttons are more complex than just changing one color...

Android buttons are made using 9-patch images and state drawables. You should take a look at [Android Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/) to generate those, you would want to select "Color Button" and it will generate the necessary images & xml for you...

Comment: As I remember, Android buttons are xml drawables

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<Button
       ...
       ...
       android:layout_margin="5dp"
       android:background="#e5e5e5"/>
```

You need to take a look at standard button drawable, it contains a shape with a certain color and also all the margins, paddings etc.